# How can I create a relative distance matrix in r using string variables?

Tags: r

I have a dataset on npi's containing information on those npi mostly in string variables

But I've simplyfied it for this example

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(51:60, sample(1:10, 10, replace = T), sample(1:10, 10, replace = T), sample(1:10, 10, replace = T)), stringsAsfactors = F)
colnames(data) <- c("npi", "a", "b", "c")
```

for instance:

```
npi a  b  c
51  6  2  1
52  6  2  6
53 10  9  2
54  7  4  7
55  7 10  5
56  8  5  7
57  7  2 10
58  5  9  3
59  8  4  6
60  1 10  2
```

I want to create a distance matrix showing the relative distances between the different NPI's
I want them to have a large distance when they're not very similar and a small distance when they are very similar. With similar I mean they share values on variables. The variables in the real dataset are names and addresses so I cannot simply use dist().

This is how I got the distance between two npi's

```
length(intersect(npi1,npi2))/3
```

But I don't know how to create a loop or a function to run through the whole dataset and give me a distance matrix like this:

```
    51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
51  0   distance 51 to 52                               
52      0                               
53          0                           
54              0                       
55                  0                   
56                      0               
57                          0           
58                              0       
59                                  0   
60                                      0
```

Would you be able to point me in the right direction which kind of loop or function to use for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#sample data
df <- read.table(text='npi a  b  c
51  6  2  1
           52  6  2  6
           53 10  9  2
           54  7  4  7
           55  7 10  5
           56  8  5  7
           57  7  2 10
           58  5  9  3
           59  8  4  6
           60  1 10  2', header=T, sep='')

#convert 1st column of data as the row index
df1 <- df[,-1]
rownames(df1) <- df[,1]

#calculate distance
library(proxy)
dist_func <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x,y))/3 
proxy::dist(df1, method = dist_func)
```

Comment: do you need the `proxy` package?  seems `dist` in base R would do too.

Comment: @Headpoint OP has string in all columns and he wants to use user defined function to calculate similarities. `dist` of base R would not be a fit for this purpose.

Comment: @Prem well, the distances are incorrect when I use this code. This is precisely the form of output that I was looking for though so thanks! But it seems as if this code transforms the original rows into lists and sees the same values as similarities regardless of whether they appear in the same variables. But this is of course important. For instance 51 and 53 get .333 where it should be 0.

Comment: @BoazKaarsemaker You would need to change your user defined function accordingly in order to have the similarities ONLY when common strings are there in the same variable.